# Verificar se já existe uma informação no banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Boas pessoal tentem me ajudar aqui nisto

Parte html

```
<form method="post" id="formulario" action="dados.php">  
   <p><label>Nome</label><input type="text" class="nome" name="nome" size="60" /></p>  
            <div id="telefone">  
        <p><label>Telefone</label><input type="text" class="fone" name="fone[]" size="15" /><span class="adicionar">Adicionar telefone</span></p>  
   </div>  
        <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btEnviar" name="btEnviar" />  
 </form>
```

Parte php

```html
<?php  

$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "teste");
                        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            echo "Erro na liga??o MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }


$nome=$_POST["nome"];





foreach($_POST['fone'] as $fone)  
{


    $inf = "select nome, tel from teste where nome = '".$nome."'";
    $res=mysqli_query($ligacao,$inf);

    while( ($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) !=null)
   {

                $infoNome=$registo["nome"];
                $infoTel=$registo["tel"];
                echo $infoNome;
                echo $infoTel;
   }


   if ($infoTel==$fone){

   }
   else{
     $sql = "insert into teste (nome, tel) values ('$nome' ,'$fone')";
     $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao,$sql);
}  
}
?>
```

O que eu quero fazer é que na parte php ao analisar todos os numeros de telemovel que a pessoa introduzir aquilo vai comparar e se já existir na base de dados não deixa acrescentar outra vez

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ser mais facil de visualizar se eu introduzisse estes números queria que apenas introduzisse o 345, 234 e o 123 uma única vez, mas não é isso que está acontecer e eu não consigo perceber porque

Comment: Os telefones não podem ser repetidos no banco de dados, correto? Uma boa alternativa é transformar a coluna teste.tel em UNIQUE. Isso vai gerar um erro ao inserir os dados pelo PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, eu não sei bem como o `mysqli` funciona, então vou exibir um método prático que eu utilizaria fazendo uso do `UNIQUE` que o bruno disse aí, vou fazer em `PDO`, mas você adapta ao seu jeito!

```
$fone = $_POST["fone"]; //recebe o post
$fone = array_unique($fone); //elimina array duplicadas
foreach($fone as $f){ //salva tudo no BD
        $this->databaseConnection();
        $prepara = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO seubanco (telefone) VALUES (:telefone)');
        $prepara->bindValue(':telefone', $f, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $prepara->execute();
}
```

Com a explicação passada, só consegui pensar nisso!

Tomara que te ajude.